# I can't figure out why my springboot application can not query database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My Spring boot application is not querying the database. I am trying to retrieve my data from mysql table and show the data in an HTML table using thymeleaf. I have added spring web, mysql driver, spring data jpa and thymeleaf dependencies. The program is running without any error but is not giving the output in the table.
Below is my code

Application properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sales?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=2556b11j

spring.jpa.properties.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Entity Class

```
package com.chigudu.Entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
    
    
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String brand;
    private String madein;
    private float price;

    
    // this is a constructor from the main class
    
    public Product() {
        super();
        
    }

//==============================================
    //this are getters and setters
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }


    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }


    public String getMadein() {
        return madein;
    }


    public void setMadein(String madein) {
        this.madein = madein;
    }


    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }


    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    
}
```

Repository Interface

```
package com.chigudu.ProductRepository;



import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.chigudu.Entities.Product;

public interface ProductRespository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    

}
```

Service class

```
package com.chigudu.ProductServices;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.chigudu.ProductRepository.ProductRespository;
import com.chigudu.Entities.Product;

@Service
public class ProductService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ProductRespository repo;
    
    public List<Product> listAll(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    public void save(Product product) {
        repo.save(product);
        
    }
    
    public Product get(Long id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    private void delete(Long id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Controller Class

```
package com.chigudu.AppControllers;


import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.chigudu.Entities.Product;
import com.chigudu.ProductServices.ProductService;

@Controller
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;
    
    // view the Application home page
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String ViewHomePage(Model model) {
        
        List<Product> listProducts=service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listProducts", listProducts);
        
        return "index";
    }
    
}
```

Thymeleaf page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Product Manager</h1>
    <table border="1">
        
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Made In</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="product : ${listProducts}">
            <td th:text="${product.id}">Product ID</td>
            <td th:text="${product.name}">Name</td>
            <td th:text="${product.brand}">Brand</td>
            <td th:text="${product.madein}">Made in</td>
            <td th:text="${product.price}">Price</td>
            <td>
            
            </td>
        </tr>
    
    </tbody>
        
 </table>
        
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you storing the data? I don't see a `post` in your controller

Comment: I stored the data using mysql workbench, I am just trying to read from the table using spring boot

Comment: Write an api to check how many rows are there in the table. In that way you can check if you are quering right schema. Use repository.count() method

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the @Repository annotation over your Repository interface.Without @Service, @Repository, @Component or @Controller annotations in a annotation based config, a class won't be considered for spring bean initialization.

Comment: thanx, I put the @Repository annotation but the problem is not gone, maybe I am missing another concept there

Comment: Please enable the spring jpa logs to see what is happening during the query.